# Trim long number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, trim, digits

For example, I got that long nubmer 1517778188788. How can i get first 6 digits from that number, like 151777 and trim another digits?

Comment: number + ' '.substring(0,6)

Comment: @NikolaAndreev If you want what you wrote to work, you need to have the concatenation in parentheses: `(1517778188788 + '').substring(0,6)`, otherwise you're just applying the `.substring(0,6)` to the empty string `''`, which does nothing other than convert the number to string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just convert a number to string and then slice it and convert it back to Number.

```
const a = 1517778188788;
const str_a = a.toString();
const result = Number(str_a.slice(0, 6));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
new String(your_number).substring(0,6)
```

(basically converting it to a string and substringing it). Don't forget to parse it back afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Applicable only when you want to strip last 7 digits, and the numbers have constant length (13 in this case). Still leaving you with first 6 ones though.

```
const nr = 1517778188788;
const result = Math.floor(nr / 10000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var num = 1517778188788; // long number
var str = num.toString(); //convert number to string
var result = str.substring(0,6)  // cut six first character
result = parseInt(result); // convert it to a number
```

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18jjc7xo/)